# Setting constraints for 3.5 inch and 4 inch screens

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

I am using auto-layout and storyboard and I am wondering if there is any way I can set "3.5 inch form factor" and "4 inch form factor" automatically (based on the screen size)?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to think about form factors in terms of autolayout. 
Imagine if you have two views: 
1st - 10 points from top
2nd - 10 point from bottom.

So you should specify constaint based on top and bottom of screen. Defining constraints that way will keep design the same, but distance between them will be different on 3.5 and 4 inches.